# Where is the __eprintf symbol defined in OS X 10.11?

Tags: macos, assert

I am compiling some asserts with `-arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode-7.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.4`. Therefore, the assert code doesn't use `__assert_rtn` but `__eprintf` instead.

Relevant snippet from **assert.h**:

```
#if defined(__ENVIRONMENT_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED__) && ((__ENVIRONMENT_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED__-0) < 1070)
#define __assert(e, file, line) \
    __eprintf ("%s:%u: failed assertion `%s'\n", file, line, e)
#else
/* 8462256: modified __assert_rtn() replaces deprecated __eprintf() */
#define __assert(e, file, line) \
    __assert_rtn ((const char *)-1L, file, line, e)
#endif
```

So far so good, except when linking time arrives, it doesn't find `__eprintf`. In which library is this defined ?

---

A way to reproduce getting `__eprintf` into the `assert`:

```
cat <<EOF >/tmp/x.c
#include <assert.h>


#ifdef __clang__
# if defined(__ENVIRONMENT_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED__) && ((__ENVIRONMENT_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED__-0) <= 1040)
#  if ! __DARWIN_UNIX03
#   warning "compiling for 10.4 (not __DARWIN_UNIX03), with __eprintf"
#  endif
# endif
#endif

int  xxx( int a)
{
   assert( a);
   return( a);
}
EOF
```

`clang -E -arch i386 -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode-7.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -o /tmp/x.txt /tmp/x.c`

---

Using above, make a dylib and observe the problem:

`clang -c -arch i386 -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode-7.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -O0 -o /tmp/x.o /tmp/x.c`

`ld -arch i386 -macosx_version_min 10.4.0 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode-7.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -t -o /tmp/x.dylib -ldylib1.o /tmp/x.o -lSystem -lgcc_s.10.4`

> These calls are destilled down from what `xcodebuild` produces.

Comment: I don't know the answer but I see that its implementation is part of Apple's open source: http://opensource.apple.com/source/clang/clang-137/src/projects/compiler-rt/lib/eprintf.c

Comment: This refers... https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2005-11/msg00183.html

Comment: A warning: The `__eprintf` there [http://opensource.apple.com/source/clang/clang-137/src/projects/compiler-rt/lib/eprintf.c]() has a wrong signature (third parameter should be unsigned), The `fprintf` has the wrong argument order (should be file, line, assertion_expression) and the `fflush` on `stderr` is superflous :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the helpful responses.

The answer turns out to be `/Applications/Xcode-7.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/7.0.2/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.10.4.a` in my particular case.

This is a library that gets added by `clang` itself behind the scenes ([DarwinClang::AddLinkRuntimeLibArgs](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/ToolChains_8cpp_source.html)). Note that this library is only for 10.4 code and seems to be tied to the compiler version.

I don't know by which magic (don't see it in the invocation) the linker decides which compiler version it needs to link for.

---

The easiest solution is to define ones own `__eprintf`, instead of messing around with the toolchain:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#if defined(__ENVIRONMENT_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED__) && ((__ENVIRONMENT_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED__-0) <= 1040)
# if ! __DARWIN_UNIX03

__attribute__((visibility("hidden")))
void __eprintf( const char* format, const char* file, 
           unsigned line, const char *expr)
{
   fprintf( stderr, format, file, line, expr);
   abort();
}

# endif
#endif


int  main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
   assert( argc == 2);
   return( 0);
}
```